# Why did Sauron change armor in the movie?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

In the Lord of the Rings (the movie), Sauron (after regaining strength and before) had different suits of armor and a different helmet. Why did he change his armor?

Comment: What do you mean by "different armour"? I can only remember the spiky armour he wore in the prologue to *Fellowship*; can you include some pictures, maybe?

Comment: Sauron appears to be wearing the same armour throughout. There's times when he takes on a "pleasing aspect" (basically looking like a tall elf)  but that's not seen in the films, other than in various [deleted scenes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Io4p00DNfF0)

Comment: Maybe you could insert the images into your question.

Comment: @Richard What the... Thank the (Dark) Lord those scenes were deleted!

Comment: I think the OP is confusing Sauron from the prolog with the Witch King from ROTK.

Comment: @TGnat - That was my thought

Comment: This question is wrong on multiple levels, *even* after the edit. The movie did NOT end when the Witch King was killed :/ I don't see any way to salvage it.

Comment: @AndresF. - Just chop off the edit. It needs asking as a new question

Comment: Here's a question. Why does Sauron wear his impractical **war armour** when he's at chillaxing at home and doing some light jewellery-making?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could you be mistaking [Sauron](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Sauron) for the [Witch King of Angmar](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Witch-king_of_Angmar)? They both wear similar (but non-identical) armour in the films.

[image]

---

For the record, on all four occasions that we see Sauron in the flesh, he's always wearing the same clobber...

LOTR: Fellowship of the Ring ([Prologue](https://youtu.be/qj139dE7tFI?t=1m22s))

[image]

LOTR: Return of the King ([Deleted Fight Scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Io4p00DNfF0))

[image]

Hobbit: Battle of the Five Armies ([Fight Scene with Galadriel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NLhypaRifcE))

[image]

Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug ([Fight Scene with Gandalf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssYpJn5YGJc))

[image]

Comment: +1 For the detailed answer with pics. However, I seriously doubt the OP is confused about The Hobbit movies or that he/she has even watched any deleted scenes. The OP *might* be confusing the Witch King with Sauron, but even then, why do they think "the movie ended when [the Witch King] was killed"?

Comment: (for completion, you could add the (awful) deleted scene about the Mouth of Sauron, maybe the OP confused him with Sauron? Then again, I seriously doubt they've watched any deleted scenes)

Comment: @AndresF. - I went overboard with the pics but I figured it was better to do a proper job for the sake of completeness than a half-assed job and hope no-one asks a similar question again in future.

Comment: @AndresF. - OP's acceptance seems to indicate that he was indeed mistaken for the Witch King.